# Backing up large file directory

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm in need of suggestions for backing up a very large file directory (500+ GB) on a weekly basis. (In a LAMP environment)

I've read about rsync, but I'm not sure how to trigger that with CRON.

Also, does anyone happen to know how much the compression in rsync shrinks the filesize? (Lets say of a 3MB .jpeg). I only ask because I can't tell how large of a backup server I will need.

Just pointing me in the right direction will be enough, I don't expect anyone to do my homework for me. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rsync) is a wiki page that has much of your question answered.

I would read the whole page to grasp one concept at a time, but the "snapshot backup" is the rsync-script-to-beat-all-rsync-scripts: it does a TimeMachine-like backup where it does differential storage going backwards in time, which is quite handy. This is great if you need chronologically-aware but minimally-sized backups.

Arch (the distro for which this wiki covers) does a really nice thing where you can just drop your scripts into a known location; you will have to adapt that to calling a script as a cron job. [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) is a fairly comprehensive introduction to cron.

I would also like to point out that rsync's compression operates on *transmission* not on *storage*. The file should be identical on your backup disk, but may take less bandwidth to transfer.

Comment: This pretty much answers all my questions! Thanks! I've got some reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to take some time regardless if it is that large - I would run a compression job through cron and then a big 'ol robocopy (windows) or robocopy equivalent on UNIX of the compressed files also through cron.

You may want to look into a RAID arrangement to deal with this (RAID 1, particularly) giant amount of data so it doesn't have to be a "job" and is done implicitly. But whether you can implement that probably depends on your resources and your situation (you will have worse write times..much worse).